# How do I translate, "by pretending that something is real?"

Tags: translation

Just as the title says. I really have no idea how to translate the word "by" in this sense. It's just a form of grammar I've never even been exposed to, so I wouldn't know where to start. Anyone know how?

Comment: May we have the whole sentence?

Comment: There was no whole sentence, this was a generic phrase I was trying to use to demonstrate the English use of "by" in this case. George Chen left a well-stated answer.

Comment: Then, it would be easy to trap ourselves in clumsy or even ill-formed Chinese using word-wise translation.

Comment: I disagree with you there. I would argue that "by" in this sense is akin to a grammar pattern, not a "word-wise translation." This is in the sense that using "by" in this sense is similar in both languages in that there is a common one-word phrase which can encompass the use of such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

通过假装...是真的的方式

By pretending the dinner is real, Peter and his friends forgot about hunger.
通过假装晚餐是真的的方式， 潘和他的朋友们忘掉了饥饿。

Or you can take a little liberty:

通过假装用晚餐的方式， 潘和他的朋友们忘掉了饥饿。

Comment: Perhaps 透过 instead of 通过?

Comment: @AndrewKozak - That's fine. I heard people from Taiwan speak like that.

Comment: Or ... "彼得和朋友們以假晚飯忘卻饑餓."

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found similar grammar that I do know how to use: 通过。
So I've just replaced all instances of this sort of "by" with "through." Seems to have identical meaning in English, so I'm fine with this.